# a good testbed to debug SCORM courseware (Applet) without LMS

Tags: debugging, moodle, scorm

What would be a nice testbed to debug JAVA APPLET based SCORM content package (eclipse).

debugging with a real LMS (like Moodle) usually requires uploading package in a zip file to LMS (slow..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADL themselves provide some compliance testing software (link [here](http://adlnet.gov/downloads/downloadpage.aspx?ID=344) I think) which  was always a good enough test for most needs (for me), and a number of free and commercial options also exist. I've heard good things about [SCORM Test Track](http://www.scorm.com/products/testtrack.aspx), but haven't used it myself.